# spotfire - Disappear lines when value in filters are selected

Tags: python, line, spotfire, tibco

I am actually new to python scripting and I have a requirement where we have a line chart (each line shows tasks and y axis the time it took to complete).

Using lines and curves I have added average, upper control and lower control limits to the line chart. I also have a filter which shows the tasks.

whenever a task is selected i want these lines(average and control lines) to appear and whenever I select more than one task or None these lines should disappear.

I saw an example which shows to create a property control for filter and then trigger the functions. Can we trigger the same functions when there is a change in the filter values instead of property control?

Comment: How familiar are you with the Python API for Spotfire? Could you do something like this: write out the selected tasks to a doc prop (list object). Read that list object into a script that executes when that doc prop changes. That script then uses API calls to toggles the check boxes for the various lines and curves you want to turn off/on if the number of objects is in that list is less than 2 or greater than or equal to two (add the line chart as a parameter to the script). I do not have the exact code a the moment, just a thought, hence the comment.

Comment: @MarkP. that sounds like it'd work! it may be a lot of work to put together but on paper it sounds like it'd do the trick :)

Comment: Marp p. It did work this way. I added a reset button to reset all the filter. Whenever I am clicking on the reset button those lines appear even when the selection is 'None' or more than 2 items. I know without seeing the dxp or codes it will be difficult to answer this question, I hope there is a way to attach files in this.

Comment: this is the code i used and which is creating the problem.                                  from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *

def resetAllFilteringSchemes():
     # Loop through all filtering schemes
     for filteringScheme in Document.FilteringSchemes:
          # Loop through all data tables
          for dataTable in Document.Data.Tables:
               # Reset all filters
               filteringScheme.ResetAllFilters()      

# Call the function
resetAllFilteringSchemes()
Document.Properties["App"]=''

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a way to react to filter changes as far as I know, but you can "recreate" the filter as a property control and execute the script when that property value changes.

typical example is for a listbox/dropdown property control representing a listbox filter.